# Angular ui-router nested view vs scope variable

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have trouble to understand the benefits using ui-router vs a scope variable for a nested view in one single controller.

For example, I can easily use a scope variable to display which page view I am at:

```
$scope.pageView = "ParentView"; // or ChildView
```

I know I can use different controllers for nested state. What else?